# how to update page without reloading the page builder?

Tags: pages, admin

is there a plugin that will make it so when i click "update" on a page, it will do it via AJAX rather than reload every time?

when using WPbakery, having to scroll back down and collapse/expand sections every time i click "update" is tedious

Comment: The WordPress block editor already works like this. If you're using a plugin like WP Bakery, that's something they would need to support, so you should contact them for help. Third party themes and plugins are off topic here.

Comment: @JacobPeattie no, im using the standard wordpress "update" button on the right-hand side. it reloads the page every time.

Comment: If you're using the Classic Editor, that's just how it works. There's no simple way to change this behaviour. If you use the Block Editor then it doesn't require a refresh every time.